# How do I get a live.com email address?

Tags: outlook.com

When registering an email address at live.com Microsoft only shows me @outlook.de/com.

Is there still a way to get a `live.com` email address?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-a-mail-live-com-email-account) which includes images:

> While the @Sign In is offered to all markets, the @live.com mail ID is not offered in all markets. This post will tell you how to create a @live.com email address.
>
> In India for example one is offered only the Sign In,
>   http://hotmail.co.in and Sign In accounts.
>
> But if you wish to create a @Sign In mail ID, simply click on this
>   Live.com link.
>
> You will be taken to this page which will ask you select a language.
>
> Selecting a language, offers you the country-specific mail IDs.
>
> Select the language as English. Click Save.
>
> The page you will be transferred to will offer you the @Sign In mail
>   ID.

Comment: That post doesn't seem to tell me in which market I need to be to get a @live.com address. It's not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is still one way to do this despite Microsoft not offering @live.com or @msn.com etc. emails, which involves using a Firefox extension called “Tamper Data”. I found out about this recently and was able to do it with multiple domain names. I and some others on YouTube before me have uploaded a tutorial on how to do this, which is relatively easy. I hope this helps you out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYZ4wKNoL4c

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.